# React onclick change variable/state to return different html

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to have html be rendered while x =true, and different html while x = false. I am not sure how to do this in react but I thought of two ways, both which do not work. Way one:

```
function App() {

  var x = true

  function switchX() {
    x = false;
    window.location.reload()
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {x ? <h1>hello</h1> : <h1>Goodbye</h1>}
      <button onClick={switchX}>Swap</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And way 2, using state:

```
function App() {
  const [x, setx] = useState(
    {
      x: true
    }
  )


  function switchX() {
    setx({x : false})
    window.location.reload()
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {x ? <h1>hello</h1> : <h1>Goodbye</h1>}
      <button onClick={switchX}>Swap</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `window.location.reload()` is not needed here as React will re-render when the state changes (in fact it would reset the state to the initial state, which is not what you want here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.. try not to think too much of state having to be an object like it was in class components... hooks allow you to abstract each variable and control each individual state.

```js
const myComponent = () => {
   const [x, setX] = useState(false);

   return (
      <>
         { x ? <div>x is true</div> : <div>x is false</div> }
         <button type='button' onClick={() => { setX(!x); }}
      </>
   );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct way of getting the value out of your state. State from hooks is not named. `useState` returns the state value without any transformations. Note that `const [y, setX] = useState({x:false})` would still compile because you're just declaring a variable called `y`.

```
function App() {
  const [{ x }, setx] = useState(
    {
      x: true
    }
  )
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use function based component you should use **useState** hook. On handleChange method just toggle the current state value.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const myComponent = () => {
const [x, setX] = useState(false);

const handleChange=()=>setX(!x)

return (
   <>
     { x ? <div>x is true</div> : <div>x is false</div> }
     <button  type='button' 
      onClick={handleChange}>Change</button>
   </>
 );
}
export default myComponent
```